# Adding Google Framework to Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, google-api

I have been using the YouTube v2 APIs for a little while and now have finally gotten around to setting up v3. So I have downloaded their frameworks/libraries from here:

```
svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only
```

And looked closely at the instructions they give for adding it to your project here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

For the life of me I cannot get my app to compile with some sort of problem. Its either and ARC problem, can't find header files or all sorts of other errors.

Hoping someone can come along who has it working and simply put some 1 2 3 steps as it would make a lot peoples lives easier as I am sure the Google APIs of all varieties are pretty relevant to a lot of people and will continue to be, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. The quickest way I could find to get the new client library up and running quickly was to install with this [CocoaPod project, called  iOS-GTLYouTube](https://github.com/brynbellomy/iOS-GTLYouTube).

CocoaPods is a really simple way to install libraries. If that's new to you, you can check out the instructions at [cocoapods.org](http://cocoapods.org).

1. Install Cocoapods if you don't have it, using your system ruby:
   `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. Create a `Podfile` located within your project with the following:

   ```
   platform :ios, '7.0'
   pod 'iOS-GTLYouTube'
   ```
3. In your project directory, using the system ruby:
   `$ pod install`